# Change Application name on iTunes connect

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

I have uploaded an application to iTunes connect, and it is approved and ready for sale, present in the app store.
I need to change the application name and some keywords..if i click edit as suggested by some stack overflow previous answers, it won't do the trick.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way I know how to do that is updating(new version in iTunes connect) your app and upload again to the app store.